# Force and Area are proportional to each other, but

Tags: forces, pressure

I have read on book the next following sentence:

> *The force is proportional to the area, for if we increase the area but keep the number of molecules per cubic centimeter the same, we increase the number of collisions with the piston in the same proportion as the area was increased. You should know that is happening on a cylinder with a piston in it.*

my question is: if we increase the area. The force should become less. Why is that? Because we make the collisions between molecules with the piston or the wall of cans or cylinder less.

we drive:  More area = less force (less pressure) as I thought .. Is that what is really happening ?!!

more area = more space = more free for molecules = less pressure = less force .

I hope someone explains to me what is author wants to tell me if I misunderstood.

Comment: "*but keep the number of molecules per cubic centimeter the same*" this means that you must increase the number of molecules precisely so that each one *doesn't* get more space than it had before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the author is telling you that if the *pressure* remains constant then the *force* is proportional to the *area*. Presumably the author is suggesting that the pressure remains constant because the "number of molecules per cubic centimeter [is] the same" so the collisions on the piston per square centimeter also remain the same.

In a sense this is tautological, as the *pressure* is the *force* divided by the *area* in question.

Comment: Absolutely right, the author Richard Feynman wrote before the previous sentence about pressure. "a cylinder with a piston in it. Now, it makes no difference what the shapes of water molecules are, so for simplicity we shall draw them as tennis balls or little dots. These things are in perpetual motion in all directions. So many of them are hitting the top piston all the time that to keep it from being patiently knocked out of the tank by this continuous banging, we shall have to hold the piston down by a certain force, which we call the pressure (pressure times the area is the force)"

Comment: Thank you, the "number of molecules per cubic centimeter [is] the same" explanation meaning increase in number of molecules to keep the molecular density (number of molecules per cubic cm same) constant made it clear 

Comment: @Deep.  Then I may have failed: the volume is not mentioned and perhaps both it and the number of molecules may stay the same, with just the shape of the piston and the relevant area changing.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a context to your question... It is badly explained and I don't really know what you're asking.

Here is what I understood :

The force on the piston depends on the number of collisions of the molecules on it and thus on the area of contact.

Take two cylinders both of volume $V$. The first of height $h_1$ and with a piston of area $A_1$ and the second of height $h_2$ and of area $A_2$. You could imagine the first as a can, with a great height compared to the section and imagine the second as a pizza, with a very tiny height compared to the section. Since the volume is the same the molecules have the same space. In the other hand, the surface where the molecules have collisions is not the same. There is more probability for a molecule in the pizza-like cylinder to have a collision with the top of the pizza than for a molecule to have a collision on the top of your can... The force is then less strong on the can-like cylinder.

But another concept is important, the concept of pressure. Take a needle and place it on the top of you hand. Now push it down. That hurts. Apply the same force to your skin but only with your finger. Nothing happens even if the force is the same. That is because the force is distributed. Pressure is defined as said by Henry by the force divided by the area.

Comment: my question is: if we increase the area. The force should become less. Why is that? Because we make the collisions between molecules with the piston or the wall of cans or cylinder less.

we drive: More area = less force (less pressure) as I thought .. Is that what is really happening ?!!

more area = more space = more free for molecules = less pressure = less force .

Comment: No. If your volume stays the same, the force is not becoming less because there are more molecules hitting the piston and each collision creates a force on the piston. More area = more force. On the other hand, since the pressure is given by $p = F/S$, the pressure stays the same because $F$ is going up, but the area $S$ too. Their augmentation "cancels" and the pressure stays the same...